# AJAX Cross-domain on symfony2

Tags: php, ajax, symfony, reactjs, cors

I am building an app with Symfony2 and React. Currently I am trying to fetch data to the react frontend via AJAX calls. No matter what I decide later, I need to know how can I configure the routing or whatever in order to be able to make cross domain AJAX calls, even for development purposes. I tried changing the truste_host in the config.yml, adding host parameter in routing but nothing seems to work. How can I get the cross-domain working, simply, without any overhead bundles?

I have the Symfony2 app on 192.168.11.128:8000 virtual machine accessible via browser and an AJAX call from http://127.0.0.1, there is no way I can get the answer, and I really need these domains to be different.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Response of the server need to have the header `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` ([More info here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS#Access-Control-Allow-Origin)).
As Example of a Symfony2 Controller Response with the value * (allowing any origin to access the resource.), you can build a Response as follow:

```
    return new JsonResponse($data, 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*'));
```

Hope this help