# Cross-Origin Request Blocked Symfony/AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, rest, api, symfony, cors

I am currently facing an error while trying to fetch datas with Angular from my Symfony API which return JSON:

> "Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8000/customers. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)."

here is a screenshot of the full result:

[image]

I know the question have been multiple times asked but I couldn't find a working answer.

When I don't try to retrieve the $session in the api controller it works and I get all the datas I need, however it don't, here is my api controller:

```
/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Get("/customers")
 */

/**
 * @Rest\View(statusCode=Response::HTTP_CREATED)
 * @Rest\Get("/index")
 */
public function getIndexAction(Request $request)
{
    $loginad = $this->getUser()->getUsername();

    $nom_ad = "******";
    $port_ad = ******;
    $compte_ad = "*******";
    $password_ad = "******";
    //parcours de l'AD
    // Connexion LDAP
    $ldapconn = ldap_connect($nom_ad, $port_ad)
    or die("Impossible de se connecter au serveur LDAP $nom_ad");
    if ($ldapconn){
        $ldapbind = ldap_bind($ldapconn, $compte_ad, $password_ad)
        or die("Impossible de se binder au serveur LDAP $nom_ad");
        if($ldapbind){
            $employeeID = false;
            $dn = "OU=CER35,DC=CeRNum,DC=dom";
            $filter="(samAccountName=$loginad)";
            $justtheseattributes = array( "ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail", "employeeid", "samaccountname");
            $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $justtheseattributes);
            $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
            for ($i=0;$i<$info["count"];$i++) {
                $employeeID = $info[$i]["employeeid"][0];
            }
            if (!$employeeID) {
                $dn = "OU=CER56,DC=CeRNum,DC=dom";
                $filter="(samAccountName=$loginad)";
                $justtheseattributes = array( "ou", "sn", "givenname", "mail", "employeeid", "samaccountname");
                $sr=ldap_search($ldapconn, $dn, $filter, $justtheseattributes);
                $info = ldap_get_entries($ldapconn, $sr);
                for ($i=0;$i<$info["count"];$i++) {
                    $employeeID = $info[$i]["employeeid"][0];
                }
            }
        }
    }

    $agent = $this->get('doctrine')
        ->getRepository('CERAgentBundle:Agent', 'agent')
        ->findByCode($employeeID);

    $session = new Session();
    $session->set('agent', $agent);

    $formatted = [
        'civilite' => $agent[0]->getCivilite(),
        'prenom' => $agent[0]->getPrenom(),
        'nom' => $agent[0]->getNom()
        ];

    return new JsonResponse($formatted);
}
```

So when I call "localhost:8000/index", a bundle for CAS server authentication also call an https URL so the user can authenticate themselves to the intranet's company, that done, they can finally retrieve results from localhost:8000/index

Here is my Angular controller:

```
angular.module('frontProfilDeveloppementApp')
.controller('ClientsCtrl', function ($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8000/customers')
        .then(function (data) {
            $scope.result = data;
        });
});
```

the nelmio_cors bundle config:

```
nelmio_cors:
    defaults:
        allow_credentials: true
        allow_origin: ['*']
        allow_headers: ['*']
        allow_methods: ['POST', 'PUT', 'GET', 'DELETE']
        max_age: 3600
        hosts: []
        origin_regex: false
```

CAS bundle configuration:

```
p_rayno_cas_auth:
server_login_url: https://extranet-authentification-******/cas-a3net/
server_validation_url: https://extranet-authentification-*****/cas-a3net/serviceValidate
server_logout_url: https://extranet-authentification-****/cas-a3net/logout
```

(security.yml) :

```
security:
providers:
    cas:
      id: prayno.cas_user_provider
role_hierarchy:
      ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
      ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: ROLE_ADMIN

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern: ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    main:
        anonymous: ~
        logout: ~
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - prayno.cas_authenticator

access_control:
    - { path: /index, roles: ROLE_USER}
```

I think my API doesn't set the same header as angular do, so the browser don't allow the fetching.

Is it possible to set headers option directly from the Angular controller, so it could match the api ones?

Comment: You can't control the headers from angular!. You need to disable web security of google chrome for testing

Comment: It works if  i disable security (my bad, edited) But anyway, i don't want to disable security, i want to add the right header (if possible)!

Answer (score 0):

You should always return an instance of a Response from Symfony and not your $customers result set directly.

Here's an example of how it can be done:
    return new JsonResponse($customers, 200, array('Access-Control-Allow-Origin'=> '*'));

You can find additional details here as well.

[AJAX Cross-domain on symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37512870/ajax-cross-domain-on-symfony2)

Comment: Can you paste the response headers from the Chrome Dev Tools Network Tab? (for the request that we're interested in) Is that header set from symfony?

Comment: "Connection : Keep-Alive
Content-Length : 0
Content-Type : text/html;charset=UTF-8
Date  : Tue, 11 Jul 2017 13:11:46 GMT
Keep-Alive : timeout=15, max=100
Location :
https://extranet-authentification-cerfrance.35-56.fr/cas-a3net/login?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000
%2Findex
Server : Apache"

Comment: i think i paste the wrong one, here's the response : Access-Control-Allow-Cred... 
true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... 
http://localhost
Cache-Control 
no-cache, private
Connection 
close
Content-Type 
text/html; charset=UTF-8
Date 
Tue, 11 Jul 2017 13:28:21 GMT
Host 
localhost:8000
Location 
https://extranet-authentification-cerfrance.35-56.fr/cas-a3net/?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000
%2Findex
Set-Cookie 
PHPSESSID=qg5cle767utjvsdcf5nc7tsmi5; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Debug-Token 
0b81f4
X-Debug-Token-Link 
http://localhost:8000/_profiler/0b81f4
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.5.38

Comment: You must be having some cache issue or another quirk because I just tested on my localhost and using that line the header is properly set in the response.

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Tue, 11 Jul 2017 13:29:15 GMT
Server: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-Length: 23
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
Connection: Keep-Alive
Content-Type: application/json.  I think you should remove the contents of your cache folder (for both dev & prod envs) , warm the cache and try again.

Comment: How could i know is the header is set from Symfony? it's a symfony url that call a https url for cas-auth.

Comment: You should still be able to handle the response after that cas-auth. Just find the right action and return a Response/JsonResonse object with that header set.

Comment: Okay i now have the json : Access-Control-Allow-Cred... 
true
Access-Control-Allow-Orig... 
http://localhost
Cache-Control 
no-cache, private
Connection 
close
Content-Type 
application/json
Date 
Tue, 11 Jul 2017 13:44:38 GMT
Host 
localhost:8000
Location 
https://extranet-authentification-cerfrance.35-56.fr/cas-a3net/?service=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A8000
%2Findex
Set-Cookie 
PHPSESSID=ntd21qkeb1fovgfdgus7ebifm4; path=/; HttpOnly
X-Debug-Token 
684fd7
X-Debug-Token-Link 
http://localhost:8000/_profiler/684fd7
X-Powered-By 
PHP/5.5.38

Comment: Yeah but you shouldn't have Access-Control-Allow-Origin: localhost but '*' - in order to get rid of the issue in angular.

Comment: I even tried this : http://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/73/how-to-bypass-access-control-allow-origin-error-with-xmlhttprequest-jquery-ajax- but without success...

Comment: Please update your post with the full code of the Symfony action that handles that request. I don't understand what are you talking about when you say this " it's a symfony url that call a https url for cas-auth." We are either talking about different things or we don't focus on the right problem.

Answer (score -1):

You can disable headers.
Solution is in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uDy_cvf4nDg&feature=youtu.be